# Quarkus Karate Test Error: Could not find option with name engine.WarnInterpreterOnly

Tags: java, runtime-error, karate, quarkus

I want to Test my Endpoints using Karate, but when starting the Test I get following Error:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find option with name engine.WarnInterpreterOnly.`

Java version: 11

Karate Maven Dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
  <artifactId>karate-junit5</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.0.RC4</version>
</dependency>
```

Feature File:

```
Feature: To test the config-resource

  Background:
    * url baseUrl

  Scenario: Add a new room
    Given path 'addRoom/testRoom'
    When method POST
    Then status 201
```

Java Test class:

```
package at.htl.mqtt.client.boundary;

import com.intuit.karate.junit5.Karate;
import io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTest;

@QuarkusTest
public class ConfigEndpointTest {

    @Karate.Test
    Karate testGetRoom() {
        return Karate.run("config-resource.feature").relativeTo(getClass());
    }
}
```

I have src/test/java as my testResource

***Edit:***

So I used the Runner API like you said but I still get the same Error.

```
import io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

@QuarkusTest
public class ConfigEndpointTest {

    @Test
    void testRoom() {
        Results results = Runner.path("config-resource.feature").relativeTo(getClass()).parallel(5);
        assertEquals(0,results.getFailCount(), results.getErrorMessages());
    }
}
```

Btw I changed Java version to 16.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling the `@Karate.Test` annotation does not "play well" with the `@QuarkusTest` one.

So I recommend using the `Runner` API. You can find an explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65578167/143475

I am not sure if you still need a method annotated with `@Test` etc, please follow the Quarkus instructions that are appropriate.

Comment: Added an Edit, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: no. please ask the Quarkus team. when you use the `Runner` API, Karate is just plain-java. remove the `karate-junit5` dependency and use `karate-core` is one more thing you can try

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this specific Exception. I got this one

```sh
superclass access check failed: class com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.PolyglotImpl (in unnamed module @0x40729f01) cannot access class org.graalvm.polyglot.impl.AbstractPolyglotImpl (in module org.graalvm.sdk) because module org.graalvm.sdk does not export org.graalvm.polyglot.impl to unnamed module @0x40729f01
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: superclass access check failed: class com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.PolyglotImpl (in unnamed module @0x40729f01) cannot access class org.graalvm.polyglot.impl.AbstractPolyglotImpl (in module org.graalvm.sdk) because module org.graalvm.sdk does not export org.graalvm.polyglot.impl to unnamed module @0x40729f01
```

But what worked for me was to use `@QuarkusIntegrationTest` instead of `@QuarkusTest`. Also for whatever reason my tests would only run on GraalVM (I tried Azul, OpenJDK and Temurin neither of which worked). These are on Java 17

As far as I know `@QuarkusIntegrationTest` runs the application in an isolated process (even going as far as running the docker image created with `quarkus.container-image.build` is `true`) as opposed to `@QuarkusTest` which doesn't as a result letting us modify the context, inject mocks etc. When using `@QuarkusIntegrationTest` the application is only accessible via network calls.

There's also some caveats when it comes to running both of these tests in a single execution according to [this](https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started-testing#mixing-quarkustest-with-other-type-of-tests).