# Can we reference tags in karate?

Tags: karate, automation-testing

i want to call the tags by referencing them to variables and then call variables to run the tests, is it possible in Karate?
for example : defining a particular tag to a variable and then calling that variable across feature files so that scenarios and feature can be specified with the tags that we want to use to run the tests.
i want to know if this is possible in karate in any way whether to use karate-config.js or something else?

Comment: this is a very vague question. my first response is please assume that it is not supported and you are welcome to contribute code to "improve" karate if needed. that said, please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67224240/143475 this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58442605/143475 and this (the `Runner` API allows you to dynamically pass tags: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71885265/143475