# What is the gradle command to run scenarios with tags?

Tags: karate

I am using Gradle 7.6, Karate 1.3.1, Java 17.0.5 and Junit 5.8.1.
I want to configure a Jenkin job for each feature to create a health check monitor. I need gradle commands to run feature files using tags @smoke, @regression, @featureName etc.,

I have tried with the following command, it worked earlier and stopped working recently.

```
./gradlew test -Dkarate.options="--tags @smoke" -Dtest.single=TestRunner#testTagsWithoutFeatureName
```

Where TestRunner is the following Java class

```
import com.intuit.karate.junit5.Karate;

public class TestRunner {

    @Karate.Test
    Karate testTagsWithoutFeatureName() {
        return Karate.run().tags("@smoke").relativeTo(getClass());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

My advice is use the `Runner` class, that is better designed for running tests in CI. The JUnit helpers are just for local-dev convenience: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65578167/143475

It should be possible to even pass a feature to `karate.options` as the last argument. Which might be more convenient than writing a Java class for every combinations. You should experiment.

Otherwise no suggestions, but if you feel there's a bug, follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have gone through the stackoverflow page and there by tried the Runner class by implementing a class similar to TestParallel in the example. I am able to run the desired tags from a feature file or all feature files. You have also mentioned Runner class is designed for running tests in CI. But I didn't understand how to achieve this without gradle support. Please explain when you have time.

Comment: @dpedagada see if this gives you some tips, else I have no other ideas: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/Debug-Server#gradle

Comment: @dpedagada I forgot to mention, typically teams put the `Runner` in a "normal" JUnit class. then all you need to do is figure out how to call that test from gradle. which I think you know how to do already - or there is plenty of references on the net

Comment: The above gradle command is working, but there is a catch. The tag mentioned in the command is only recognized when it is the last tag above the scenario. 
i.e., The same command works when @smoke is represented like this 
`@query, @smoke`
And it throws `org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: no features or scenarios found: [classpath:]` when the tags are represented as 
`@smoke, @query`

Is this a bug or my usage is wrong?

Comment: @dpedagada put the folder or claspath at the end, it should work. else no one else has reported this, submit an issue or contribute code please

Comment: Added classpath like this `./gradlew test -Dkarate.options="--tags @smoke classpath:Features/foo.feature" -Dtest.single=TestRunner#testTagsWithoutFeatureName `, But the issue still exists. 
Will raise an issue in the repo. Thanks Peter.

Comment: The issue is with the comma separated tags, I wish the documentation covered the usage of multiple tags. I would have avoided this mistake. While going through the source code, I found that tags are not comma separated but white space separated or WSLF in the feature file. So it should be `@smoke @query` not `@smoke, @query`, Thank you.

Comment: @dpedagada please help improve the docs via a PR, it is all open source