# Run Test cases from karate and Junit5 module together

Tags: java, maven, testing, karate, junit5

I would like to run test cases at test project that include 2 modules karate framework and Junit5, and I want to specify the tag name for the test cases that I need to run.

I tried
`mvn clean install -Dkarate.options="--tags @pass" -Dgroups=@pass` but it doesn't work as karate modules doesn't fetch scenarios with tag name `@pass`.
and when I remove `@-Dgroups=@pass` it works karate scenarios works fine.

so I think there is an interfere between environment parameter karate.options and groups.

how can I run test cases with specific tag name with one command in both modules?

Comment: I have no idea about this, hope someone good at junit can answer. if it helps, karate does not "require" JUnit if you use the `Runner` API directly: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65578167/143475